# Azure Maps - How to set drawing manager layers z-index to the top?

Tags: azure-maps

In my design page, the user will be creating/drawing new shapes, in addition to adding image overlays. I'm finding that any shapes drawn using the drawing manager are rendering underneath any image overlays added to the map, see below:

[image]

I'd like to know how to achieve a couple of tasks:

1 - How to set the drawing manager so any shape (rectangle/point/circle etc be default is always added as an upper/top layer when the drawingcomplete event has fired, that way the shapes will always appear above any images added to the map.

2 - How to programatically change the order of the various layers created during design, given the user may want to adjust the z-index of the various layers to suit their own endering requirements.

The MS docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.layermanager?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest) is not really helping me understand how to achieve the above, but also doesnt mention anything about shapes/layers that currently reside within the drawing manager.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer but along the right tracks...

We can retrieve the shapes (drawing manager layers) from the drawing manager so we have a reference to them.

When i add an image overlay, before actually adding/rendering it to the map, i would first get the shape layers from the drawing manager, then remove them from the map.

Next we add the image overlay to the map and add the shape layers back in as well, its the order that we add/remove the layers that seems to be relevant here.

Once i had added all layers back to the map in the chosen order, i was still able to put the drawing manager into edit mode and select the shape for editing, so i beleive this will work as my solution going forwards.

```
// Create the image layer
var imageLayer = new atlas.layer.ImageLayer({
    url: 'myImageUrl,
    coordinates: coordinates
})
// Then get the existing shapes (layers) from the DM
var layers = drawingManager.getLayers();
console.log(layers);
// Remove the shapes.
map.layers.remove(layers.polygonLayer); // polygonLayer as an example...
// Add new image overlay, then the shapes
map.layers.add([imageLayer, layers.polygonLayer]);
```

[image]